# FusionChart Export to PDF not exporting images on Chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, fusioncharts

So I have the following chart :

[image]

As you can See I have little images(annotations) in the chart and am using the built-in function to export the chart to PDF(As I cant find code to allow me to do it via the controller or via iTextSharp) - This works great though, as it gives a number of choices to export to(PDF,PNG,JPG etc.) - However, the little images as you see are not displayed when exported to PDF for example.

Is there a property that needs to be set such as the one to allow the exporting to be done : `exportenabled='1'` ?

Thank in advance.

Comment: Which version of **FusionCharts** are you using? The latest version of FusionCharts **(ver 3.11.0)** supports image export. 
Note: The images must be of same domain and not cross domain.
Here is the link of latest version of FusionCharts  - http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js

Comment: Honestly, I am actually not sure. It is however the free version. I would assume that Annotations being exported with the chart is not supported on the free version ?

Comment: There is **no difference** between the free version and the licensed version as per the **features** of FusionCharts.

Comment: Ah ok. I had a quick look and it is on version 3.5. I copied everything from what you sent and replaced my FusionChart.js and re-ran, but it still does not export the images. I have even added a background image and it is also not adding this when exported...

Comment: Please ensure that you use the latest version of FusionCharts (ver 3.11.0) and image should be from the **same domain**.

Comment: Thanks @Arnab003. As mentioned in my previous post, I did try it and it still didnt work. It is on the same domain. In this case it is on my local. Do you have a solution ?

Comment: I even tried downloading the latest files, but its giving me the following error : JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'setChartMessage

Answer (score 2):

@AxleWack

Try this code -

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first chart using FusionCharts Suite XT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js?cacheBust=82"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js?cacheBust=82"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "column2d",
        "renderAt": "chartContainer",
        "width": "500",
        "height": "300",
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource":  {
          "chart": {
            "caption": "Monthly revenue for last year",
            "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart",
            "xAxisName": "Month",
            "yAxisName": "Revenues (In USD)",
            "exportEnabled": "1",
            "canvasBgAlpha": "50",
            "bgImageVAlign": "middle",
            "bgImageHAlign": "middle",
            "bgImageScale": "120",
            "bgImage": "http://localhost:8888/Sample/fc.png",
            "theme": "fint"
         },
         "data": [
            {
               "label": "Jan",
               "value": "420000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Feb",
               "value": "810000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Mar",
               "value": "720000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Apr",
               "value": "550000"
            },
            {
               "label": "May",
               "value": "910000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Jun",
               "value": "510000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Jul",
               "value": "680000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Aug",
               "value": "620000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Sep",
               "value": "610000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Oct",
               "value": "490000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Nov",
               "value": "900000"
            },
            {
               "label": "Dec",
               "value": "730000"
            }
          ]
      }

  });
revenueChart.render();
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <center><div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Put this **HTML** in the root directory of your **localhost** under folder name **Sample** (i.e., rootDir -> Sample -> index.html).

Here, the image name is 'fc.png'. Put an image in the **Sample** folder (i.e., rootDir -> Sample -> fc.png).

Make sure if you use **localhost** in the domain name to access the HTML page through browser (eg. http://localhost:8888/Sample/index.html), give value for **bgImage** attribute as http://localhost:8888/Sample/fc.png, else if you use IP address in domain name to access the **HTML** page through browser, for eg. http://192.168.0.160:8888/Sample/index.html, the value for **bgImage** atrribute will be like - http://192.168.0.160:8888/Sample/fc.png.

The domain name should be same for both the image and html.

The above is the solution for local setup. You may also use **FusionCharts** [exporter handlers](http://www.fusioncharts.com/extensions/) for various technologies like ASP .Net, php, Ruby On Rails, Java EE.

Now try exporting the chart, it will be exported with the images.

Thank You! Hope I have been able to explain you properly. :)